# $X_n\in \{0,1\}$, $X_n\to 0$ in probability, $N(n)\uparrow \infty$ a.s., and $X_{N(n)}\to 1$

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

> Give an example with $X_n\in \{0,1\}$, $X_n\to 0$ in probability, $N(n)\uparrow \infty$ a.s., and $X_{N(n)}\to 1$ a.s.

Let $P(X_n=0)=p_n$. Here $\epsilon,\delta>0$

$P(|X_n|>\epsilon)\to 0$.

Now, $P(X_n>\epsilon)=1-p_n$, if $\epsilon<1$, otherwise $0$. Then, $p_n\to 1$

$P(|X_n-1|>\epsilon)=P(X_n<1-\epsilon)=p_n$, if $\epsilon<1$, otherwise $0$.

I need to find $N(n)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_{N(n)}-1|>\delta)< \infty$

So, basically I need to think about $\delta<1$. But could not find how to proceed. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: $X_{N(n)}\to 1$ a.s.? Or in probability?...or what?

Comment: @Shashi a.s. ${}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find $X_n$, using Borel-Cantelli, such that $\fbox{1}~ \mathbb{P}(X_n=1 \text{ i.o.})=1$.

Then define $N(n)=\inf\{k>n| X_{k}=1      \}$. Equation $\fbox{1}$ implies that $N(n)<\infty$ almost surely, therefore $X_{N(n)}=1$ almost surely. Also, since $N(n)>n$, $N(n)\rightarrow\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: Let, $P(X_n=0)=p_n$. Now $P(X_n=1\space\text{i.o.})=1$, if $\sum P(X_n=1)=\infty\Rightarrow \sum (1-p_n)=\infty$. Now, I know $p_n\to 1$.

Choosing, $n$ such that $p_n\leq 1-\dfrac{1}{n}$, I can achieve such conclusion.

Is it ok?

Comment: @Stat_prob_001 Yes, this will do. (Of course $X_n$ have to be independent)

Comment: I have a problem here: I know that $X_n\to 0$ a.s. iff for all $\epsilon>0$, $P(|X_n|>\epsilon\space\text{i.o.})=0$,which only happens if $\sum P(|X_n|>\epsilon)<\infty$. Analogously here I have to find $p_{N(n)}$ such that $\sum P(|X_{N(n)}-1|>\epsilon)<\infty$. Will the above $N(n)$ work here?

Comment: (continued) (if $\epsilon<1$): $\sum P(|X_{N(n)}-1|>\epsilon)=\sum p_{N(n)}$, I think... (maybe my calculation is wrong. Can you please identify my fault?)

Comment: @Stat_prob_001 Here $X_{N(n)} = 1$ a.s., so $\mathbb{P}(|X_{N(n)} - 1     |=0)=1$. Important point: Notice that $N(n)$ is not a constant number it is an integer valued random variable. So, it is not correct to say $\mathbb{P}(|X_{N(n)} -1  |) = p_{N(n)}$.